# How to Count word based onkeyup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to count word based onkeyup then show alert if words < min words

here what i try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#submit').on('click', function(){
  checkPassword();
       var password = $("#password").val();
       var confirmpassword = $("#konfpassword").val();
       var email = document.getElementById("display1");
       var username = document.getElementById("display2");
       var minword = 7;
       if(password !== confirmpassword){
         alert('Password Tidak Sama!');
           return false;
       } if (email.style.display !== "none") {
               alert('Email Sudah Digunakan!');
            return false;
        } if (username.style.display !== "none") {
               alert('Username Sudah Digunakan!');
            return false;
        } 
    });

function checkPassword(){
  var minword = 7;
  if (minword > Number($('#password').val().length)){
    alert('Password Terlalu Pendek!');
    return false;
  }
}
</script>
```

i want alert only show after i clicked submit and password short then min words.

Comment: Is `#submit` a form submission button?

Comment: @DKyleo yes....

Comment: I know it seems like an obvious question - just had to be certain, as there is no html code in your question for me to cross-check against.

Comment: Instead of `document.getElementById('password').onkeyup = ...` you should write `if` here like `if(minword > document.getElementById('password').value.length){...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mixing jQuery and JavaScript like you did is not a good idea.

You can create a function so that the function can be called on separate events from multiple elements. I also prefer `input` instead of `keyup`.

```js
$('#submit').on('click', function(event){
   checkPassword(event);
});
$('#password').on('input', function () {
  //checkPassword();
});

function checkPassword(e){
  var minword = 7;
  if (minword > Number($('#password').val().length)){
    alert('Password Terlalu Pendek!');
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input type="password" id="password"/>
<button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: why not using onkeyup?

Comment: @Jazuly, you can still use that but `input` serves the purpose better here.

Comment: im using alert, so when user click submit it will showw alert when password is to short

Comment: @Jazuly, you can use `alert` and that will show the message when the password is short....updated the answer as well.....thanks

Comment: i want alert show when submit is clicked and password short then minwords

Comment: @Jazuly, simply comment the function call inside the `input` handler function. Check the updated answer.

Comment: alert is show but data still send to databases, check my full code, im update my code in question.

Comment: @Jazuly, instead of returning false use `e.preventDefault();`. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: whats different fale and prevent?

Comment: @Jazuly, that's really great to know:)

Answer (score 1):

You can this. Try it.

```
var minWord = 7;
var $password = $('#password');

$('#submit').click(function(e){
    if(!checkValid()) {
        e.preventDefault(); // this is stopping submit!
        e.stopPropagation(); // this is stopping bubbling
    }
});

$password.keyup(function () {
    checkValid();
});

function checkValid() {
    if (this.value.length < minWord) {
        alert('Password Terlalu Pendek!');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: In your `checkValid` function `this` will be `window` object not `password`.

Comment: @Jazuly Instead of `this.value.length` use `document.getElementById('password').value.length` then it will work.

Comment: @Jazuly I edited comment. perhaps can I see your console message?

Answer (score 0):

Writing password keyup event in the function of Submit click event is not way to call 2 events so create a separate events & Single function

```
 var minword = 7;
$("#password").keyup(function (event) {
     CheckPasswordCount();  
});
$('#submit').on('click', function(){     
     CheckPasswordCount(); 
});

function CheckPasswordCount()
{
   if(minword > $('#password').val().length)
   {
      alert('Password Terlalu Pendek!');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
<input type="text" oninput="get_len($(this).val())" placeholder="Write Something...">

<div id="alert_msg"></div>
```

---

```
 function get_len(input){
  var min_val = 7;
  if(input.length < min_val){
      $("#alert_msg").text('Oops!');
  }
  else
  {
  $("#alert_msg").text('ok');
  }
}
```